# TinyMCE: Force all content into a bulleted list?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, html-lists

Is it possible to force all content posted in a tinyMCE textbox to be wrapped in a bulleted list?

i.e. All content would be wrapped in a `<ul>` and each line break in the text box would create a new `<li>`

I know I can add it as an option but is there a way to force all text into a list?

Comment: Seems that what you want would be better done without TinyMCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [force_root_block](http://wiki.moxiecode.net/wiki.php/Configuration%3aforced_root_block) which defaults to "p" or "div".
But i do not think this will work. In my tinymce the p's got replaced with ul's, but you would have to insert the li's using an own plugin, because there is no such default functionalitiy in tinymce.

Comment: I ended up using force_root_block to create the <li>'s and a javascript function to add the <ul>:

setup : function(ed) {
            // Gets executed after DOM to HTML string serialization
            ed.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
                // State get is set when contents is extracted from editor
                if (o.get) {
                    // condition could be more sophisticated
                    if (o.content.indexOf('<ul>') == -1) {
                        o.content = '<ul>' + o.content + '</ul>';
                    }
                }
            });
        }

Comment: thx for providing your solution, so that others may use it too